# Default values for field type options in schema.xml

Tags: solr

Which are the default values for the field type options in the schema.xml file?

In the [solr documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) you will find just default value for the autoGeneratePhraseQueries option.

I'm especially interested in the omitNorms, omitPositions and omitTermFreqAndPositions options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know and of Solr 4.5 these hold true.

```
+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+
|   Type    | indexed | stored | omitNorms |omitTermFreqAndPositions| tokenized |
+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+
| binary    | true    | true   | false     | true                   | false     |
| boolean   | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| date      | true    | true   | false     | true                   | false     |
| double    | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| float     | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| int       | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| long      | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| pdate     | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| pdouble   | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| pfloat    | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| pint      | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| plong     | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| random    | true    | true   | false     | true                   | false     |
| string    | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| tdate     | true    | true   | false     | true                   | false     |
| tdouble   | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| tfloat    | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| tint      | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
| tlong     | true    | true   | true      | true                   | false     |
+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+
| textField | true    | true   | false     | false                  | true      |
+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+
```

I had not found these values either, so I have written some test to print something similar to this.

All options (properties) you do not find here, default to false.

The test to print the default values [can be found in GitHub](https://github.com/chriseverty/solrsample/blob/master/src/main/java/de/cheffe/solrsample/DefaultFieldTypesTest.java).

Basically it

- creates a schema with all field types
- does not override any options
- starts the core with that schema within a EmbeddedSolrServer
- from that EmbeddedSolrServer fetch the parsed SchemaFields
- print their options (properties)